# How to MySQL Event Scheduler with dynamic datetime?

Tags: php, mysql

Table table_cache is like this:

```
    id   cache_name     created date
    1    cache one      2016-03-06 01:20:04
    2    cache two      2016-03-06 09:40:34
    3    cache three    2016-03-06 11:40:04
```

MySQL script to truncate table_cache is like this:

```
CREATE 
EVENT `deleteEvent`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 MINUTE STARTS '2016-04-06 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
TRUNCATE table_cache;
```

It will truncate table_cache every 30 minute star 2016-04-06 00:00:00

But that's not what I want. I want truncate table_cache every 30 minute star field created_date from table table_cache

So, based on the above table:

```
id=1, truncate on 2016-03-06 01:50:04
id=2, truncate on 2016-03-06 10:10:34
id=3, truncate on 2016-03-06 12:10:04
```

Whether it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

`TRUNCATE` is, by definition, an operation that removes every single row from the table. It isn't what you want here.

What you want is probably something along the lines of

```
DELETE FROM table_cache
       WHERE created_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

which will remove all entries that are older than 30 minutes at the time the query is run.

You will need to decide how often to run this query based on how exact you need the lifetime to be. (For instance, if you run the query on every half hour, a row that is created at 8:01 will only become eligible for deletion at 8:31, so it will persist until the query runs at 9:00, making it actually last 59 minutes instead of 30. Whether this is a problem will depend on your application.)

Comment: So, for my case, it's not using MySQL Event Scheduler ?

Comment: You could use the event scheduler to run that query periodically, just as you've done in your example.

Comment: So, MySQL Event Scheduler can not using dinamyc datetime?

Comment: It's technically possible (by scheduling a separate event to delete each row), but will perform poorly with lots of rows. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I had no other choice. So, the complete script : CREATE 
EVENT `deleteEvent`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 MINUTE STARTS '2016-04-06 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
DELETE FROM table_cache
       WHERE created_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) . Like that?

Comment: You would need to set the event as `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE`. Setting the event as `ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE` makes it only run once, then get deleted (making `EVERY 30 MINUTE` pointless).

Comment: CREATE 
EVENT `deleteEvent`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 MINUTE STARTS '2016-03-23 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
DELETE FROM hotel_destination_cache
       WHERE created_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) . Like that?

Comment: the query not success

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093418/how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time-and-what-time-is-it-like-notifica