# How to find the time elapsed since a date time and what time is it like notification facebook?

Tags: php

My code is like this :

```
<?php
    function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
        $now = new DateTime;
        $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
        $diff = $now->diff($ago);

        $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
        $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

        $string = array(
            'y' => 'year',
            'm' => 'month',
            'w' => 'week',
            'd' => 'day',
            'h' => 'hour',
            'i' => 'minute',
            's' => 'second',
        );
        foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
            if ($diff->$k) {
                $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
            } else {
                unset($string[$k]);
            }
        }

        if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
        return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
    }

    $created_date = '2016-06-28 23:30:00';

    echo time_elapsed_string($created_date);
?>
```

I want to make like datetime in notification facebook

It is like this :

June 26 at 11:45

yesterday at 7:00

12 minutes ago

I want to make like that

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: @Arsh Singh, I still have difficulty displaying datetime like datetime in facebook

Comment: you can call a function which return full date as per your format when !empty($string['y']) || $string['m'] || !empty($string['w']). When $string['d'] < 2 show the text 'yesterday'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your function. Please add required validation

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
        $now = new DateTime();

        $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
        $diff = $now->diff($ago);

        $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
        $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

        $string = array(
            'y' => 'year',
            'm' => 'month',
            'w' => 'week',
            'd' => 'day',
            'h' => 'hour',
            'i' => 'minute',
            's' => 'second',
        );
        foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
            if ($diff->$k) {
                $v = $diff->$k ;//. ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');

            } else {
                unset($string[$k]);
            }
        }

        if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);

     if(!empty($string['y']) || !empty($string['m']) || !empty($string['w']) )
        {
            echo showdate($datetime,'w')."<br>";
        } 
     elseif(!empty($string['d']) )
        {
            if($string['d'] > 1)
            {
              echo showdate($datetime,'w')."<br>";
            }
            else
            {
               echo showdate($datetime,'d')."<br>";
            }
        }
     elseif(!empty($string['h']) )
        {
         echo implode(', ', $string) . 'h ago';//"<br>";
        }
        elseif(!empty($string['i'])  )
        {
          echo implode(', ', $string) . 'mints ago';//"<br>";
        }
        elseif( !empty($string['s']))
       {
         echo 'just now';//"<br>";
        }
     // return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
    }


function showdate($dt,$type)
{
    $mydt  = new DateTime($dt);
    if($type == 'd')
    {
        $str = 'Yesterday at '.$mydt->format('H:i:s ');
    }
    elseif($type == 'h')
    {
        //$str = 'Yesterday at '.$mydt->format('H:i:s ');
    }
    else
    {
        $str = $mydt->format('M d');
        $str .= ' at '.$mydt->format('H:i:s ');
    }

    return $str;
}
    $created_date = '2016-06-29 04:50:00';

    echo time_elapsed_string($created_date);
```

Comment: I have tried it. The results are not in accordance

Comment: I change like this : `$created_date = '2016-06-25 14:10:00';`, The result : Yesterday at 14:10:00. It's wrong

Comment: Check my updated function

Comment: I try change like this : `$created_date = '2016-06-29 16:00:00';`, The result : just now. Should : 22 minutes ago

Comment: Check my updated function

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175735/how-to-get-data-in-function-extend-controller